# SWIFT Alamofire Graph issue

Tags: ios, swift, graph, charts, alamofire

I am new to IOS development. Please help me with issue. I am not getting data on Y axis. Fetching data through Alamofire using webAPI. Data is coming nil. Same code is working fine with UIViewController table. I am getting the response. But when using in Graph it is not working.

Issue: I am using Alamofire to parse WebAPI. 'SLPercent' is the value which i want to display on Y-axis.But xml value coming as nil.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, ScrollableGraphViewDataSource {
        var xml = try! XML.parse("")
        var graphView: ScrollableGraphView!
        var currentGraphType = GraphType.bar
        var graphConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        var label = UILabel()
        var reloadLabel = UILabel()

        // Data for the different plots
        var numberOfDataItems = day

        // Data for graphs with a single plot
        /*lazy var simpleLinePlotData: [Double] = self.generateRandomData(self.numberOfDataItems!, max: 100, shouldIncludeOutliers: false)
        */
        lazy var barPlotData: [Double] =  self.generateRandomData(self.numberOfDataItems!, max: 100, shouldIncludeOutliers: false)

        // Data for graphs with multiple plots
        lazy var blueLinePlotData: [Double] = self.generateRandomData(self.numberOfDataItems!, max: 50)
       // lazy var orangeLinePlotData: [Double] =  self.generateRandomData(self.numberOfDataItems!, max: 40, shouldIncludeOutliers: false)

        // Init
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let user = "ndbd@gmail.com"
            let passwort = "xdc"

            var url = URL(string: "https://ceef")
            let configuration =  URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10

            let credentialData = "\(user):\(passwort)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
            let headers = ["Accept": "application/xml","Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    Alamofire.request(
                                      url!,
                                      method: .get,
                                      parameters: nil,
                                      encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                                      headers:headers)
                        .responseString
                        {           response in
                            debugPrint(response)
                            print(response.request)  // original URL request
                            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
                            print(response.data)     // server data
                            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                            if response.result.value != nil
                            {
                                self.xml = try! XML.parse(response.result.value!)
                            }
                            }
            }
             // self.CallWebAPI()
            // Labels for the x-axis
            let now = Date()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
            let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
            var xAxisLabels: [String] =  self.generateSequentialLabels(self.numberOfDataItems!, text: nameOfMonth);
            graphView = createMultiPlotGraphOne(self.view.frame)
            graphView.topMargin = 200
            graphView.bottomMargin = 20
            addReloadLabel(withText: "RELOAD")
            self.view.insertSubview(graphView, belowSubview: reloadLabel)
            setupConstraints()
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "⬅", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backAction))
        }

        func backAction()
        {
            //print("Back Button Clicked")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)  {
            super.viewDidLoad()
          //  self.CallWebAPI()
            graphView = createMultiPlotGraphOne(self.view.frame)
            graphView.topMargin = 200
            graphView.bottomMargin = 20
            addReloadLabel(withText: "RELOAD")
            self.view.insertSubview(graphView, belowSubview: reloadLabel)
            setupConstraints()
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)  {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            graphView = createMultiPlotGraphOne(self.view.frame)
            graphView.topMargin = 200
            graphView.bottomMargin = 20
            addReloadLabel(withText: "RELOAD")
            self.view.insertSubview(graphView, belowSubview: reloadLabel)
            setupConstraints()
        }
        // Implementation for ScrollableGraphViewDataSource protocol
        // #########################################################
        // You would usually only have a couple of cases here, one for each
        // plot you want to display on the graph. However as this is showing
        // off many graphs with different plots, we are using one big switch
        // statement.
        func value(forPlot plot: Plot, atIndex pointIndex: Int) -> Double {
            switch("bar") {
            // Data for the graphs with a single plot
            case "bar":
                return barPlotData[pointIndex]
            default:
                return 30
            }
        }


         func label(atIndex pointIndex: Int) -> String {
            // Ensure that you have a label to return for the index
            let now = Date()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
            let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
            var xAxisLabels: [String] =  self.generateSequentialLabels(self.numberOfDataItems!, text: nameOfMonth);
            return xAxisLabels[pointIndex]
        }

        func numberOfPoints() -> Int {
            return numberOfDataItems!
        }

        // Creating Different Kinds of Graphs  
        // min: 0
        // max: 100
        // Will not adapt min and max reference lines to range of visible points
        private func createBarGraph(_ frame: CGRect) -> ScrollableGraphView {
           let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: frame, dataSource: self)
            graphView.topMargin = 200
            graphView.bottomMargin = 20
            // Setup the plot
            let barPlot = BarPlot(identifier: "bar")
            barPlot.barWidth = 25
            barPlot.barLineWidth = 1
            barPlot.barLineColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#777777")
            barPlot.barColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#555555")
            barPlot.adaptAnimationType = ScrollableGraphViewAnimationType.elastic
            barPlot.animationDuration = 1.5
            // Setup the reference lines
            let referenceLines = ReferenceLines()
            referenceLines.referenceLineLabelFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 8)
            referenceLines.referenceLineColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            referenceLines.referenceLineLabelColor = UIColor.white
            referenceLines.dataPointLabelColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

            // Setup the graph
            graphView.backgroundFillColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#333333")
            graphView.shouldAnimateOnStartup = true
            graphView.rangeMax = 100
            graphView.rangeMin = 0

            // Add everything
            graphView.addPlot(plot: barPlot)
            graphView.addReferenceLines(referenceLines: referenceLines)
            return graphView
        }

        fileprivate func createMultiPlotGraphOne(_ frame: CGRect) -> ScrollableGraphView {
            let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: frame, dataSource: self)
            graphView.topMargin = 200
            graphView.bottomMargin = 20
            // Setup the first plot.
            let blueLinePlot = LinePlot(identifier: "multiBlue")
            blueLinePlot.lineColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#16aafc")
            blueLinePlot.adaptAnimationType = ScrollableGraphViewAnimationType.elastic

            // dots on the line
            let blueDotPlot = DotPlot(identifier: "multiBlueDot")
            blueDotPlot.dataPointType = ScrollableGraphViewDataPointType.circle
            blueDotPlot.dataPointSize = 5
            blueDotPlot.dataPointFillColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#16aafc")
            blueDotPlot.adaptAnimationType = ScrollableGraphViewAnimationType.elastic

            // Setup the reference lines.
            let referenceLines = ReferenceLines()
            referenceLines.referenceLineLabelFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 8)
            referenceLines.referenceLineColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            referenceLines.referenceLineLabelColor = UIColor.white
            referenceLines.relativePositions = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
            referenceLines.dataPointLabelColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)

            // Setup the graph
            graphView.backgroundFillColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#333333")
            graphView.dataPointSpacing = 80
            graphView.shouldAnimateOnStartup = true
            graphView.shouldAdaptRange = true
            graphView.shouldRangeAlwaysStartAtZero = true

            // Add everything to the graph.
            graphView.addReferenceLines(referenceLines: referenceLines)
            graphView.addPlot(plot: blueLinePlot)
            graphView.addPlot(plot: blueDotPlot)

            return graphView
        }

        // Constraints and Helper Functions
        // ################################
        private func setupConstraints() {

            self.graphView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            graphConstraints.removeAll()
            let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.graphView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.graphView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.graphView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.graphView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            graphConstraints.append(topConstraint)
            graphConstraints.append(bottomConstraint)
            graphConstraints.append(leftConstraint)
            graphConstraints.append(rightConstraint)
           self.view.addConstraints(graphConstraints)
        }

        // Adding and updating the graph switching label in the top right corner of the screen.
        private func addLabel(withText text: String) {

            label.removeFromSuperview()
            label = createLabel(withText: text)
            label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
            let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: label.frame.width * 1.5)
            let tapGestureRecogniser = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap))
            label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecogniser)
            self.view.insertSubview(label, aboveSubview: reloadLabel)
            self.view.addConstraints([rightConstraint, topConstraint, heightConstraint, widthConstraint])
        }

        private func addReloadLabel(withText text: String) {
            reloadLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            reloadLabel = createLabel(withText: text)
            reloadLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: reloadLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
            let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: reloadLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: reloadLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: reloadLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: reloadLabel.frame.width * 1.5)
            let tapGestureRecogniser = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(reloadDidTap))
            reloadLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecogniser)
            self.view.insertSubview(reloadLabel, aboveSubview: graphView)
            self.view.addConstraints([leftConstraint, topConstraint, heightConstraint, widthConstraint])
        }

        private func createLabel(withText text: String) -> UILabel {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            label.text = text
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
            label.layer.cornerRadius = 2
            label.clipsToBounds = true
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.sizeToFit()
            return label
        }

        // Button tap events
        func didTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            currentGraphType.next()
            self.view.removeConstraints(graphConstraints)
            graphView.removeFromSuperview()
            switch(currentGraphType) {
            case .bar:
                graphView = createBarGraph(self.view.frame)
                addReloadLabel(withText: "RELOAD")
                addLabel(withText: "BAR")
            }
            self.view.insertSubview(graphView, belowSubview: reloadLabel)
            setupConstraints()
        }

        func reloadDidTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
           // TODO: Currently changing the number of data items is not supported.
            // It is only possible to change the the actual values of the data before reloading.
            // numberOfDataItems = 30
            // data for graphs with a single plot
            barPlotData = self.generateRandomData(self.numberOfDataItems!, max: 100, shouldIncludeOutliers: false)
            blueLinePlotData = self.generateRandomData(self.numberOfDataItems!, max: 50)
            let now = Date()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
            let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
            var xAxisLabels: [String] =  self.generateSequentialLabels(self.numberOfDataItems!, text: nameOfMonth);
            xAxisLabels = self.generateSequentialLabels(self.numberOfDataItems!, text: nameOfMonth)
            graphView.reload()
        }


        // Data Generation
        private func generateRandomData(_ numberOfItems: Int, max: Double, shouldIncludeOutliers: Bool = true) -> [Double] {
            var data = [Double]()
            var counter = 1
            for _ in 0 ..< numberOfItems
            {
                for Result in xml["WebAPiResponse","Result"]
                {
                    let SLPercent = Result["SLPercent"].text!;
                    let Date = Result["DateCST"].text!;
                    let DateFromService = Int(Date.substring(to:Date.index(Date.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)))
                    if (counter == DateFromService!)
                    {
                        data.append(Double(SLPercent)!)
                    }
                }
                data.append(Double(counter))
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            return data
        }

        private func generateRandomData(_ numberOfItems: Int, variance: Double, from: Double) -> [Double] {
            var data = [Double]()
            for _ in 0 ..< numberOfItems {
                let randomVariance = Double(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: variance)
                var randomNumber = from
                if(arc4random() % 100 < 50) {
                    randomNumber += randomVariance
                }
                else {
                    randomNumber -= randomVariance
                }
                data.append(randomNumber)
            }
            return data
        }

        private func generateSequentialLabels(_ numberOfItems: Int, text: String) -> [String] {
            var labels = [String]()
            for i in 0 ..< numberOfItems {
                labels.append("\(text) \(i+1)")
            }
            return labels
        }

        // The type of the current graph we are showing.
        enum GraphType {
            case bar
            mutating func next() {
                switch(self) {
                case .bar:
                self = GraphType.bar
                }
            }
        }

        override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
            return true
        }

    }
```

Comment: I just fixed the quotes in your code.. You are using two different kinds of quotes (the straight double quotes and the curvy ones).

Comment: You are missing the fact that `Alamofire.request` is async, so when you do `self.xml = try! XML.parse(response.result.value!)`, you don't reload anything afterwards. And I don't know why you do it in ` DispatchQueue.main.async{}`

Comment: What should i do?